Why are my output values displaying E when they shouldn't be that long?
When running a program for calculating investor loans, my program provides an output of owner future value that is extremely long and contains an "E". I'm not sure if my formulas are wrong or if I've coded something wrong, since I am fairly new to Java.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvestorLoans {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
      
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount invested: \n");
    double investorAmount = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("Please enter the current company valuation (in millions): \n");
    double userValue = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("\n");

    double currentValue = userValue * 1000000;

    System.out.println("Please enter the estimated rate of growth: \n");
    double userRate = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("\n");

    double growthRate = userRate / 100;
    
    System.out.println("Please enter the percentage of company given for investment: \n");
    double userPercentage = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("\n");

    double investorPercentage = userPercentage / 100;

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of investment years: \n");
    double time = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("\n");


    double companyFutureValue = currentValue * Math.pow((1 + growthRate), time);

    double investorFutureValue = investorPercentage * companyFutureValue;
    
    double ownerFutureValue = companyFutureValue - (investorAmount + investorFutureValue);


      
        System.out.println("The amount invested is: \t" + investorAmount);
    System.out.println("The current valuation is: \t" + userValue + " million");
    System.out.println("The growth rate is: \t" + userRate + "%");
    
    System.out.println ("The investor percentage is: \t" + userPercentage + "%");
    System.out.println ("The investment years is: \t" + time);


    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println(companyFutureValue);
    System.out.println(investorFutureValue);
    System.out.println("The owner future value is: \t" + ownerFutureValue);
    }
}



When running the program, I input the values 2000000 (amount invested, 10 (valuation in millions), 60 (rate of growth percentage), 20 (investment percentage), 5 (investment years).
I expected a rational number up to 2-3 decimal places as the outcome for owner future value, but instead got 8.188608000000003E7.
Please enter the amount invested:

2000000


Please enter the current company valuation (in millions):

10


Please enter the estimated rate of growth:

60


Please enter the percentage of company given for investment:

20


Please enter the number of investment years:

5


The amount invested is:         2000000.0
The current company valuation is:       10.0 million.
The growth rate is:     60.0%.
The investor percentage is:     20.0%.
The investment years is:        5.0

The owner future value is:      8.188608000000003E7


You get something in the 80_000_000 range (which is 8.xxx x 10^7 which Java prints out as 8.xxxxE7) which looks reasonable.

as (too) often advised on this site, do not use floating point numbers like double and float to represent currency - they often are not precise enough and special care must be taken with rounding
